# Datatable update from another component

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using the datatables table plugin for jquery. I have another component that uses Ajax to retrieve an object from the server. I'd like to update the database with this object. I'm struggling on how to piece this together. The Ajax returns an object that is in the format that the datatable will accept for data. But how can I update the datatable from another components Ajax call? I'm using python flask and jinja2 templating. Here is the javascript as it currently exist:

```
$(function() {
    var container = document.getElementById('visualization');
    var items = new vis.DataSet({{documents|safe}});
    var options = {};
    var timeline = new vis.Timeline(container, items, options);

    timeline.on('select', function (properties) {
        $.getJSON('/getDependencyHistory', {
            uuid: properties.items[0]
        }, function(data) {
            console.log("Place this into the datatable");
        });
        return false;
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#example').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: is the data from the getJSON a full table update or just updating certain rows?  At the moment, I am assuming that each change on the selectbox completely repopulates the datatable with new data.

Comment: btw, $(document).ready(function()   and $(function() { are doing the same thing so you can actually move the datatable up with the other code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a really simple one that "fools" the ajax call.

go to http://live.datatables.net/nesadivo/1/edit

Click on Run With JS button to initialize everything.  Click on the go button to go get the data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // created a global variable for the datatable to us to find the data
     var dtData = null;

     // On the button click, use regular ajax to get the data
     $("#btnGo").on("click", function(){
         $.ajax({url:"http://live.datatables.net/examples/server_side/scripts/server_processing.php",

             success:function(cData){
                    // on success, set the global variable then reload table
                    dtData = JSON.parse(cData);
                    $('#example').DataTable( ).ajax.reload();
                },
                error:function(err){debugger;}}  ); 
      });

      // initialize the table on page load
      $('#example').DataTable( {
          "ajax": function(a,callback,c){
               callback(dtData);
           }
       });
     });
```